# Using SQL to filter specific value and then remove duplicate row

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

Let say I have a table called ‘ABC’ in access database with the following settings :

```
Des Date Mid ... ISIN order 
 A.  B.   C. ...  D.    E
 F.  G.   H  ...  I.    J
 K.  L.      ...  N.    O
 P.  Q.      ...  S.    O
 L.  I.   U. ...  I.    P
```

I need to first select all the empty cells from column ‘Mid’,and then delete the duplicated rows if column ‘order’ values are duplicated, only leave one record, so that all the empty from column ‘Mid’ will have no duplicated value in column ‘order’

*no primary key nor unique identifier in my table

Result I want:

```
 Des Date Mid ... ISIN order 
 A.  B.   C. ...  D.    E
 F.  G.   H  ...    I.    J
 K.  L.      ...    N.   O 
 L.  I.   U. ...     I.    P
```

Now, with the selected empty cells in column ‘Mid’, there is no more duplicate value in column ‘order’

my database is so large that I can only simulate this table for reference, What is the SQL statement of this commend?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Does the table have a primary key?  Do you just want a `select` query or to delete the data?

Comment: I can only think of using a select query to select all value under column ‘order for those empty in column ‘mid’, but then I duno why to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one or more of your columns is a primary key, you can use:

```
delete from t
   where t.Mid = "" and
         t.des > (select min(t2.des)
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.Mid = t.Mid and
                        t2.Order = t.Order
                 );
```

This arbitrarily assumes that `des` is the primary key.

Comment: @chinshinglam . . . You need a set of columns that are unique.